# d3.v3 scatterplot with all circles the same radius

Tags: javascript, d3.js, scatter-plot, nvd3.js

Every example I have found shows all of the scatter plot points to be of random radii. Is it possible to have them all the same size? If I try to statically set the radius all of the circles will be very small (I'm assuming the default radius).  However, if I use Math.random() as in most examples there are circles large and small.  I want all the circles to be large. Is there a way to do that? Here's the code snippet forming the graph data using Math.random() (this works fine for some reason):

```
function scatterData(xData, yData) 
{
  var data = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < seismoNames.length; i++) 
  {
    data.push({
      key: seismoNames[i],
      values: []
    });

    var xVals=""+xData[i];
    xVals=xVals.split(",");
    var yVals=""+yData[i];
    yVals=yVals.split(",");

    for (var j = 0; j < xVals.length; j++) 
    {
      data[i].values.push({
        x: xVals[j], 
        y: yVals[j], 
        size: Math.random()
      });

    }
  }

  return data;
}
```

Math.random() spits out values between 0 and 1 such as 0.164259538891095 and 0.9842195005008699. I have tried putting these as static values in the 'size' attribute, but no matter what the circles are always really small.  Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update:** The NVD3 API has changed, and now uses `pointSize`, `pointSizeDomain`, etc. instead of just `size`.  The rest of the logic for exploring the current API without complete documentation still applies.

---

For NVD3 charts, the idea is that all adjustments you make can be done by calling methods on the chart function itself (or its public components) before calling that function to draw the chart in a specific container element.

For example, in the example you linked too, the chart function was initialized like this:

```
 var chart = nv.models.scatterChart()
               .showDistX(true)
               .showDistY(true)
               .color(d3.scale.category10().range());

 chart.xAxis.tickFormat(d3.format('.02f'));
 chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format('.02f'));
```

The `.showDistX()` and `.showDistY()` turn on the tick-mark distribution in the axes; `.color()` sets the series of colours you want to use for the different categories.  The next too lines access the default axis objects within the chart and set the number format to be a two-digit decimal.  You can play around with these options by clicking on the scatterplot option from the  ["Live Code" page](http://nvd3.org/livecode/).

Unfortunately, the makers of the NVD3 charts [don't have a complete documentation](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/wiki/_pages) available yet describing all the other options you can set for each chart.  However, you can use the javascript itself to let you find out what methods are available.

### Inspecting a NVD3.js chart object to determine options

Open up a web page that loads the d3 and nvd3 library.  The [live code page](http://nvd3.org/livecode/) on their website works fine.  Then open up your developer's console command line (this will depend on your browser, search your help pages if you don't know how yet).  Now, create a new nvd3 scatter chart function in memory:

```
var testChart = nv.models.scatterChart();
```

On my (Chrome) console, the console will then print out the entire contents of the function you just created.  It is interesting, but very long and difficult to interpret at a glance.  And most of the code is encapsulated so you can't change it easily.  You want to know which properties you can change.  So run this code in the next line of your console:

```
for (keyname in testChart){console.log(keyname + " (" + typeof(testChart[keyname]) + ")");}
```

The console should now print out neatly the names of all the methods and objects that you can access from that chart function.  Some of these will have their own methods and objects you can access; discover what they are by running the same routine, but replacing the `testChart` with `testChart.propertyName`, like this:

```
for (keyname in testChart.xAxis){console.log(keyname + " (" + typeof(testChart.xAxis[keyname]) + ")");}
```

---

Back to your problem.  The little routine I suggested above doesn't sort the property names in any order, but skimming through the list you should see three options that relate to size (which was the data variable that the examples were using to set radius)

- size (function)
- sizeDomain (function)
- sizeRange (function)

Domain and range are terms used by [D3 scales](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales), so that gives me a hint about what they do.  Since you don't want to scale the dots, let's start by looking at just the size property.  If you type the following in the console:

```
testChart.size
```

It should print back the code for that function.  It's not terribly informative for what we're interested in, but it does show me that NVD3 follows D3's getter/setter format: if you call `.property(value)` you set the property to that value, but if you call `.property()` without any parameters, it will return back the current value of that property.

So to find out what the size property is by default, call the `size()` method with no parameters:

```
testChart.size()
```

It should print out `function (d) { return d.size || 1}`, which tells us that the default value is a function that looks for a size property in the data, and if it doesn't exist returns the constant 1.  More generally, it tells us that the value set by the size method determines how the chart gets the size value from the data.  The default should give a constant size if your data has no `d.size` property, but for good measure you should call `chart.size(1);` in your initialization code to tell the chart function not to bother trying to determine size from the data and just use a constant value.

Going back to the live code scatterplot can test that out.  Edit the code to add in the size call, like this:

```
 var chart = nv.models.scatterChart()
               .showDistX(true)
               .showDistY(true)
               .color(d3.scale.category10().range())
               .size(1);

 chart.xAxis.tickFormat(d3.format('.02f'));
 chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format('.02f'));
```

Adding that extra call successfully sets all the dots to the same size -- but that size is definitely not 1 pixel, so clearly there is some scaling going on.

First guess for getting bigger dots would be to change `chart.size(1)` to `chart.size(100)`.  Nothing changes, however.  The default scale is clearly calculating it's domain based on the data and then outputting to a standard range of sizes.  This is why you couldn't get big circles by setting the size value of every data element to 0.99, even if that would create a big circle when some of the data was 0.01 and some was 0.99.  Clearly, if you want to change the output size, you're going to have to set the `.sizeRange()` property on the chart, too.

Calling `testChart.sizeRange()` in the console to find out the default isn't very informative: the default value is null (nonexistent).  So I just made a guess that, same as the D3 linear scale `.range()` function, the expected input is a two-element array consisting of the max and min values.  Since we want a constant, the max and min will be the same.  So in the live code I change:

```
.size(1);
```

to

```
.size(1).sizeRange([50,50]);
```

Now something's happening!  But the dots are still pretty small: definitely not 50 pixels in radius, it looks closer to 50 square pixels in area.  Having size computed based on the area makes sense when sizing from the data, but that means that to set a constant size you'll need to figure out the approximate area you want: values up to 200 look alright on the example, but the value you choose will depend on the size of your graph and how close your data points are to each other.

--ABR

P.S.  I added the NVD3.js tag to your question; be sure to use it as your main tag in the future when asking questions about the NVD3 chart functions.

Answer (score 1):

The radius is measured in pixels.  If you set it to a value less than one, yes, you will have a very small circle.  Most of the examples that use random numbers also use a scaling factor.

If you want all the circles to have a constant radius you don't need to set the value in the data, just set it when you add the radius attribute.

Not sure which tutorials you were looking at, but start here: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tutorials

The example "Three little circles" does a good step-by-step of the different things you can do with circles:
http://mbostock.github.io/d3/tutorial/circle.html

Comment: thanks for the reply! This is the example I had been using: http://nvd3.org/ghpages/scatter.html.  Following the example you led me to and using {var circle = d3.select('#my_graph svg').selectAll("circle");
    circle.attr("r", 30);} changes the legend circle radii, but not the radii of the circles in the graph.

Comment: Ah, you needed to specify that you were using a NVD3 chart method -- very different from drawing a chart yourself.  I'll add another answer.

Comment: @AmeliaBR It looks like the real question is discovered only after sixth or seventh comment of the poster... And the most important thing is usually the last said...

Comment: @VividD Quite frankly, considering the total lack of documentation on the NVD3 site and github, I can see how a new user would get confused.   But it's true, a lot of time the first hurdle is figuring out what the problem is when all someone knows is that it doesn't work...