# nvd3 scatter chart circle size not working

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js, scatter-plot

I am trying to change the size of the circles in the scatter plot. I use the attribute size but even if I change it to 10, 100 etc, the size of the circles is not increasing. I tried using `.sizeRange([minArea, maxArea])` and the maximum size increases. I am unable to understand how the `size` effects the perceptible sizes. Is it relative size?

**Edit**

If you have

```
function(groups, points) {
var data = [],
  shapes = ['circle', 'cross', 'triangle-up', 'triangle-down', 'diamond', 'square'],
  random = d3.random.normal();

for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
  data.push({
    key: 'Group ' + i,
    values: []
});

for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
     data[i].values.push({
        x: j
      , y: j
      , size: j
    });
  }
}
}
```

Even if we change the j loop from `j<4`to `j<8`, the size of the largest circle remains the same. We can try the code [here](http://nvd3.org/livecode/index.html#codemirrorNav).

Comment: Can you update the question with the code you have got or a link to [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with your code.

Comment: @shabeer90 please see my edit above

Comment: Check out these two answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20909793/d3-v3-scatterplot-with-all-circles-the-same-radius/20914196#20914196 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104118/nvd3-scatter-chart-circle-radius/21104407#21104407  Together, they should help you figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

As of 1.7.1 version, can you use the attribute pointRange([minArea,maxArea]):

In a javascript object:

```
chart.pointRange([45,50]);
```

In JSON options:

```
chart:{
    ...
    pointRange:[45,50],
    ...
 }
```

To my, the values 45 and 50 were sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to make sure you have the right new version (1.8.5) of the scripts:

```
<link href="http://nvd3.org/assets/css/nv.d3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="http://nvd3.org/assets/lib/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script src="http://nvd3.org/assets/js/nv.d3.js"></script>
```

then, use sizeRange:

```
chart
.showDistX(true)
.showDistY(true)
 .color(d3.scale.category10().range())
 .size(1).sizeRange([100,100]);
```

This is working for me.
Having said that, the shapes do not work in this version.
It's a terrible plotting package.